# How can I find this recurrence relation? My approach seem to be wrong.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**QUESTION:**

> A string that contains only 0s, 1s, and 2s is called a ternary string.
>   Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length
>   n that do not contain two consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s.

--

**My approach:**

Let's define a *in-valid* string, as the ternary string that contain two consecutive 0's or 1's, $b_n$. Now, let $a_n$ be the number of *valid* strings. We need to substract the number of *in-valid* ($b_n$) strings from the number of ternary strings, $3^n$. To count $b_n$, use the sum rule: partition the set of strings, depending on what digits start the string:

1. The string that starts with a 2: $b_{n-1}$ ways to finish the string.
2. The string that starts with a 1:

   - The remaining strings that start with a 0: $b_{n-2}$ ways to end the string.
   - The remaining strings that start with a 1: $3^{n-2}$ ways to finish the string.
   - The remaining strings that start with a 2: $b_{n-2}$ ways to finish the string.
3. The string that starts with a 0:

   - The remaining strings that start with a 0: $3^{n-2}$ ways to end the string.
   - The remaining strings that start with a 1: $b_{n-2}$ ways to finish the string.
   - The remaining strings that start with a 2: $b_{n-2}$ ways to finish the string.

Summing it up, $b_n = b_{n-1} + 4b_{n-2} + 2\cdot(3^{n-2})$.

Note that the initial conditions are: $b_0 = b_1 = 0$.

Also note that this recurrence relation counts the number of *in-valid* strings; that is the ternary strings that **contain** two consecutive 0's or 1's. In order to obtain the number of *valid* ternary strings we would need to substract this from the total number of ternary strings, $3^n$. Hence we could use $a_n = 3^n - b_n$ where $a_n$ is the number of (*valid*) ternary strings that do not contain two consecutive 1's or 0's.

> I tried for $b_2$ and $b_3$ but it does not give the right answers.
>   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

What you're missing is that there are more than $b_{n-2}$ invalid ways to finish a string that starts with `10` -- namely, the rest of the string could start with `0` but otherwise be valid. And similarly for strings that start with `01`.

---

The natural way to set up a recurrence would be to let $a_n$ be the number of *valid* strings of length $n$ that start with `0` or `1`, and $c_n$ be the number of valid strings that start with `2`. We then have
$$ \begin{align} a_{n+1} &= a_n + 2c_n \\
c_{n+1} &= a_n + c_n \end{align} $$
and we get
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ c_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{pmatrix}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix} $$
and we can then try to diagonalize the matrix to find a closed solution to the recurrence.

In this particular case, however, it is easier to set $p_n=a_n+c_n$ (these are the numbers we're really interested in) and calculate
$$p_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+c_{n+1}=2a_n+3c_n=2p_n + c_n = 2p_n + a_{n-1}+c_{n-1} = 2p_n+p_{n-1}$$
So a single second-degree recurrence for the result would be
$$ p_n = 2p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} $$

This can be solved using standard techniques. The characteristic polynomial has roots $1\pm\sqrt 2$, and the exact solution turns out to be
$$ p_n = \frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}}2 =
\left[\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}}2\right] $$
where $[{\,\cdot\,}]$ rounds to the *nearest* integer.

---

**Bonus question:** Is there a straightforward combinatorial interpretation of the recurrence $p_n=2p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$?

Comment: I understand the two recurrence equations.  Is it possible to explain how to arrive at the matrix equation?.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: The two recurrence equations are the same as $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1}\\c_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_n\\c_n\end{pmatrix}$$ which you can just keep applying step for step until you reach $(a_1,c_1)$ which has the known values $(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to know the last digit of the string to decide what the possible next digits are.  So there are three "states:" $0$, $1$ and $2$; if $x_n$, $y_n$ and $z_n$ are the numbers of strings of length $n$ ending in each one of these states, it's clear that
$$\pmatrix{x_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}\\z_{n+1}}=
  \pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&1}\pmatrix{x_{n}\\y_{n}\\z_{n}}
$$
Let $A$ be this matrix; if you set $x_0=0$, $y_0=0$ and $z_0=1$ (so that all $1$-long strings are OK, you have
$$\pmatrix{x_{n}\\y_{n}\\z_{n}}=A^n\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}.$$
The answer to your problem is $c_n=x_n+y_n+z_n$.

To compute this, note that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $z^3-z^2-3 z-1$, whose roots are $-1$ and $\sqrt2\pm1$.  Thus $c_n$ satisfies the recurrence $c_n=c_{n-1}+3c_{n-2}+c_{n-3}$, and has the closed form $c_n=A(-1)^n + B(\sqrt2+1)^n+C(\sqrt2-1)^n$, where the constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ can be found by looking at $c_0=1$, $c_1=3$, and $c_2=7$; we find $A=0$, $B=(1+\sqrt2)/2$ and $C=(1-\sqrt2)/2$, so
$$c_n=\frac12(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}+\frac12(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the symbolic method to establish a system of generating functions.

Let A(x) be the g.f. for the number of valid words that are empty or start with a 1 or start with a 2.

Let C(x) be the g.f for the number of valid nonempty words that start with a 2.  We need to be familiar with the subtleties of the symbolic method.

The system:  $A(x) = 1 + x + x A(x) + 2x C(x), C(x) = x A(x) + x C(x)$ gives

$A(x) = \frac{1 - x^2}{1 - 2x + x^2}$ and $C(x) = \frac{x + x^2}{1 - 2x + x^2}$.

We desire A(x) + C(x) and the sequence is given in Sloane's OEIS A078057.

Comment: How do you get $A(x)=1+x+xA(x)+2xA(x)$?

Comment: I am sorry, the equation for A(x) had a typo which I have corrected now.   A valid word  that is empty or starts with a 0 or a 1 can be constructed  by prepending a 0 or 1 to a valid word that starts with a 2 ( which accounts for the term 2*x*C(x) ) OR prepending a 0 or a 1 to a word that starts with a 1 or 0 respectively ( this is the x*A(x) term ).  Now when we prepend to the empty word we really have two choices ( 0 or 1) so we have to add the term x.  The term 1 is the empty word.